# In C++, the * is used for what three things?

Tags: c++

I know the `*` operator is overloaded for multiplication and pointing.
Is the 3rd use uniary? If so, could someone elaborate?

Comment: [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) is a list of all the operators and their precedence.

Comment: It is is really overloaded for multiplication and pointing, it is rather already built into the language.

Comment: `T* x = nullptr;` `4 * 2`; `*x = a;`.

Answer (score 3):

When used as the pointer dereference operator it is a unary operator.

This is because in that context, it only takes one argument, namely the pointer.

You do see * in 5 contexts (other than quoted strings):

1. as a multiplication operator
2. as pointer deference
3. as multiplication assignment *=
4. to form part of a type; e.g. int*
5. as part of /* and */ comment blocks

In (1) and (2) and (3), it is acting as an operator. C++ allows you to overload operators.

Comment: Are not .* and ->* each considered as two separate operators? You can't for example write `operator.*`... for overloading. Or can you? just starting my c++

Comment: according to [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access#Built-in_pointer-to-member_access_operators) they are built in operators.  `.*` is not overloadable but `->*` [is](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d4e58ab92a9c91fb)

Answer (score 0):

From what I know:

1. First use: to declare a pointer:

   ```
   int * ap;
   ```

   `ap` is an integer pointer.
2. To dereference a pointer. `*ap` gives the value stores at the address pointer to by the pointer `ap`.
3. Multiplication, e.g. `int a = 5*2;`

Comment: In case 1, it is not an operator